# what is the range in value of levelweights in opencv detectmultiscale3?

Tags: opencv

I would like to know what range of values are returned by the levelWeights variable in OpenCV detectMultiScale3 so that I can understand the confidence level of the detection. What are minimum and maximum values? What is a good level to use as a cutoff for detection?

```
import cv2

faces, rejectLevels, levelWeights = faceCascade.detectMultiScale3(image_array, scaleFactor=1.05, minNeighbors=1, outputRejectLevels=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I did a few tests with a few subjects using the Haar Cascade Eye Detection. What I did was

- Eyes wide open (abnormally raising the brows)
- Eyes fully open (normal way an average person does it)
- Eyes Half open (Squinting, but making sure the eye balls show a bit)
- Eyes Closed (fully closed).

The sweet spot for me is anything above 3.
When eyes are fully closed, levelWeights are usually empty, but sometimes I get values that are way below 1. Anything below 3 is either half closed or fully closed.

So I guess you might have to do your own experiments to find the sweet spot.